# gcc 5.3 -Wunused-parameter in generic lambda

Tags: gcc, c++14, gcc-warning

After GCC update to gcc-5.3 I am getting `-Wunused-parameter` warning in
a code sample that didn't had issues previously.

`g++ prog.cc -std=c++14 "-Wunused-parameter" "-Werror"`

```
int main() {
  [](auto... xs) { return sizeof...(xs); }(42);
}


prog.cc:2:14: error: unused parameter 'xs#0' [-Werror=unused-parameter]
   [](auto... xs) { return sizeof...(xs); }(42);
              ^~
```

gcc HEAD http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/WdTXg4WqprlNpGgR

Both gcc-5.2 and clang does not report this warning

gcc 5.2 http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/lkHAkgvMfrtUPMZI

clang HEAD http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/XqdS0Ma5Vvlamg3F

Is it a bug or feature?

Answer (score 1):

[Bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68965) already reported by Vittorio Romeo